# Fulfilling The Conditions of a Triangle in Kotlin

Tags: if-statement, kotlin, conditional-statements, java.util.scanner

I wrote the code below in Kotlin to check if three values a, b and c can make up a triangle. The law has it that these three conditions must be true : (a + b > c); ( b + c > a); ( a + c > b), where a, b and c are the value of the sides of the triangle. I wrote the code below and while running, found out that it gave **no output** and no error too.

I later got the code correct by replacing the three if statements below with this: **(a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b)**. Please I need help on why it gave no output. Thanks

import java.util.*
fun main(args: Array) {
val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

```
// write your code here
val a = scanner.nextInt()
val b = scanner.nextInt()
val c = scanner.nextInt()


if ((a + b) > c)  { 
    if ((b + c) > a) {
        if ((a + c) > b){
    println("YES")
} else {
    println("NO")
    }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your updated code? In your current code there will only be output if the first two conditions are true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's fix the indentation in your code:

```
if (a + b > c) {
    if (b + c > a) {
        if (a + c > b) {
            println("YES")
        } else {
            println("NO")
        }
    }
}
```

Does that help to illustrate what's going on?

If the first or second `if` condition is false, then it skips the rest.  Only if both are true does it check the third, and print either "YES" or "NO" accordingly.

(You usually see this sort of confusion when people omit the braces; without them, the `else` condition applies to the nearest, innermost `if`, which can be surprising.  But here the braces are there to make it clear!)

If you always want it to print something, then there are three main options.  First, collapse the conditions to a single `if`, as you have already discovered:

```
if (a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b) {
    println("YES")
} else {
    println("NO")
}
```

That's the simplest way, but can get very unwieldy if the conditions are big or complex.

Second, add an `else` branch for each `if`:

```
if (a + b > c) {
    if (b + c > a) {
        if (a + c > b) {
            println("YES")
        } else {
            println("NO")
        }
    } else {
        println("NO")
    }
} else {
    println("NO")
}
```

This is long-winded and repetitive, but can be necessary (e.g. if an inner `if` is preceeded by other statements).

Thirdly, you could move the conditions outside the `if`:

```
val checkA = a < b + c
val checkB = b < c + a
val checkC = c < a + b

if (checkA && checkB && checkC) {
    println("YES")
} else {
    println("NO")
}
```

That can be easier to read when the condtions get complicated, especially as you can assign nice simple descriptions for them.  And you can do whatever calculations you need in between.  But the down-side is that there's no short-circuiting: it always evaluates all the conditions, even if the first one is false.  That matters if the later conditions have any side-effects, or involve a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    println(checkTriangle(1, 2, 3))
}

fun checkTriangle(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): String {

    return when (a + b <= c || a + c <= b || b + c <= a) {
        true -> "YES"
        else -> "NO"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If u are writing in C, I suppose that this part of your body `(a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b)`

should be like that + u doesn't return any result.

```
if ((a + b > c ) && (b + c > a) && (a + c > b)) 
return ("YES")
else 
return ("NO")
```